# Showing a modal When onclick method is called of <a>

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, salesforce

i am using a salesforce platofrm.in which i have access to only onclick function of a button .i have to launch a modal like this code

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

instead of setting these attributes `href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal`

how to show modal when user click on the link using onclick function of javascript please guideline

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On click of the button you can use the `show` method as given in the [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zI1jbq?p=preview)

Comment: for this i should have to include bootstrap.min.css in my html page or including bootstrap.min.js is enough for showing the modal ??

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta you need both the css and js files

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle for hide show, don't need to use show and hide

```
$("#myModalID").modal('toggle');
$('#myModalID').modal('show');
$('#myModalID').modal('hide');
```